# Non Javafx equivalent for Task

Tags: java, class, javafx

In a non-JavaFX application I would like to have the same Class like Task.

A Thread which executes something and is able to return its progress.

Is there something that could perform a task similar to the above mentioned?

Comment: have a look at [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get()) and [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Comment: FutureTask supports no progress-update

Comment: could you clarify "non-JavaFX Application"?

Comment: Why don't you want to you use a class that is part of the standard Java Runtime ?

Comment: @Spotted `Task` updates properties, such as `progress` on the FX Application thread. If the application is not a JavaFX application, the FX toolkit will not be initialized, and the FX application thread won't be started. Consequently, `updateProgress(...)` will fail with an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: The Usecase: I have a Webservice which starts an Task (implemented now as a Callable). When the user asks the Webservice again for the task, the Callable should return his progress (status). In javaFx you can use the Task-Class for this. In non-Java-Fx Applications there is nothing for that usecase.

Comment: In swing, there is the [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: @Hesk Since you appear to need only a tiny part of what `Task` provides, you should add the information in your last comment to the question.

Comment: @James_D Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Task` class adds a bunch of functionality to a `FutureTask`, but all of the non-obvious parts are to do with providing *observable* properties and ensuring they are updated on the FX Application Thread. It sounds like you don't need any of the difficult parts: you are querying the task to check its progress (so you don't need observability, i.e. callbacks to be invoked when the progress changes) and you don't have an FX Application Thread on which to schedule updates.

So, for example, if you want to track progress, just add the appropriate property to your `Callable` implementation. If you want the progress to be accessible from multiple threads, use an atomic reference to represent the progress internally (or at least make it `volatile`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable ;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong ;

public class MyCountingTask implements Callable<Void> {

    private AtomicLong progressCount = new AtomicLong();
    private final long max = 1000 ;

    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {

        for (int count = 0; count < max ; count++) {

            progressCount.set(count);

            // in real life, do actual work instead of sleeping...
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        progressCount.set(max);

        return null ;
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return 1.0*progressCount.get() / max ;
    }
}
```